# Firefox extension: How to include jQuery to manifest.json

Tags: jquery, firefox-addon

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://me.peace.com/*"],
      "js": ["peace.js", "jquery.js"]
    }
  ],
```

Hi All,

This is a piece of my script in `manifest.json` for Firefox extension.

I added `"jquery.js"` and it stopped working. Is there another way I can add `"jquery.js"`?

Without `"jquery.js"` it works.

Comment: Is `jquery.js` in the same folder as `peace.js`?

Comment: Also, I believe the files are loaded in the order of their index, this means that if `peace.js` uses jQuery (probably does) you will need `jquery.js` to be listed first

Comment: @DelightedD0D, yes, of course.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You know, @DelightedD0D, it worked when I put it first. Oh, my dumb head... Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received help from @DelightedD0D, what I did is I just replaced both .js files:

This didn't work:

```
"js": ["peace.js", "jquery.js"]
```

This worked:

```
"js": ["jquery.js", "peace.js"]
```